# Facebook social plugin share button

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I am using a Facebook social plugin share button, I  want to capture the event whether the user shares the event or not.

Is there a way to check whether the user shared it or not using plugin only?

Comment: what have you tried so far? there are many stackoverflow threads about this topic already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `FB.ui` method provided by the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript), you can pass a callback as the second argument and check for the `post_id` on the response object.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://www.example.org/',
    picture: 'http://placehold.it/400x400',
    caption: 'Title',
    description: 'Some description...'
}, function (response) {
    if (response.post_id) {
        // This post was shared
    } else {
        // This post was not shared
    }
});
```

More information can be found in the [Facebook share documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web).